# Accessing specific field of a generic struct passed to a variadic function

Tags: go, generics

Say I have a generic `struct` called `foo`:

```golang
type foo[T any] struct {
    data T
}
```

I have a variadic function that I want to pass some `foo`s to. They could be any type of `foo`. My understanding is that because a `foo[int]` is different to a `foo[string]`, I need to define my ellipsis as type `any`, like so:

```
func bar(things ...any) {
    for _, v := range things {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

And this indeed works.

```golang
func main() {
    a := foo[string]{"cheese"}
    b := foo[int]{42}

    bar(a, b)
}
```

---

My problem is that I want to specifically access the `data` field in each `foo`. But if I define `bar` like this,

```golang
func bar(things ...any) {
    for _, v := range things {
        fmt.Println(v.data)
    }
}
```

the compiler gets understandably upset, since `things` could be *anything* and, therefore, there is no guarantee they have the field `data`.

I *know* there will be a field called `data` since I'm always passing `foo`s, but I can't specify that I'll only pass `foo`s, like this,

```golang
func bar(things ...foo) {
    for _, v := range things {
        fmt.Println(v.data)
    }
}
```

because the type of `foo` isn't specified.

---

How can I pass an unspecified number of `foo`s to `bar` and then access the `data` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution seems to be to use reflection and to access the field using `FieldByName`:

```golang
func bar(things ...any) {
    for _, v := range things {
        x := reflect.ValueOf(v)
        fmt.Println(x.FieldByName("data"))
    }
}
```

It's not clear to me though if this would be considered a cludge and/or dangerous for some reason or other. Presumably, I'd need some checking in there to ensure that everything in `things` is actually a `foo` of some variety or I could be trying to access a field that doesn't exist.

Comment: this solution is acceptable (keeping in mind that fields should be exported); the main issue is that using an `any` vararg allows you to "hide" that different *instantiations* of `foo` are being passed to the function, which falls under the case of having different generic types within the same container. After all `...any` is treated as `[]any` in the function body. If the possible instantiations of `foo` aren't many you can also use a type switch